# Regular expression for links

Tags: php, regex

I have a string which has urls and I need to replace that urls with links but only if the links are in a white list of domains. I have a pattern which replaces the urls with links but I don't know how to put that list of accepted domains in the pattern. I use the following code:

```
$pattern = '/\b((http(s?):\/\/)|(?=www\.))(\S+)/is';

preg_replace($pattern,
         '<a href="$1$4" target="_blank">$1$4</a>',
         $string);
```

Comment: What does your whitelist look like?  Is it an array like this: `$whitelist = array('google.com', 'yahoo.com');`?

Comment: @Quixrick yes, something like this. It can also be inside the regular expression, there will be no more than 5 hosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you do your REGEX stuff, you can just check to see if the domain appears in the whitelist.

```
<?php

$whitelist = array('http://www.google.com', 'http://www.yahoo.com');

$string = 'http://www.google.com';

if (in_array($string, $whitelist)) {

    $pattern = '/\b((http(s?):\/\/)|(?=www\.))(\S+)/is';

    $string = preg_replace($pattern, '<a href="$1$4" target="_blank">$1$4</a>', $string);

}

print $string;
```

EDIT:

So for this, I turned the string into an array and then looped through each part of that array.  Then I checked to see if that array part matched any of the whitelist words.  If so, then I plopped in your REGEX stuff; If not, it got left alone.  Then I added each part back to an array, which I turned back into a string.  I also applied CodeAngry's suggestion of using the `~` instead of `/` for matching URLs.

```
<?php

$domain_array_new = array();    
$whitelist = array('google.com', 'yahoo.com');

$string = 'subdomain.google.com Lorem yahoo.com Ipsum is simply microsoft.com dummy text www.google.com of the printing and typesetting industry.';

$domain_array = explode(' ', $string);

foreach ($domain_array AS $domain_part) {

    foreach ($whitelist AS $whitelist_domain) {

        if (preg_match('/'.preg_quote($whitelist_domain, '/').'/', $domain_part)) {

            $pattern = '~\b((http(s?)://)|(?=www\.))(\S+)~is';
            $domain_part = preg_replace($pattern, '<a href="$1$4" target="_blank">$1$4</a>', $domain_part);

        }

    }

    $domain_array_new[] = $domain_part;

}

$string = implode(' ', $domain_array_new);

print $string;
```

Now, this works somewhat, but you need to do some more work on your regular expression.  The only URL that it picked up was `www.google.com`.  It did not pick up `yahoo.com` or `subdomain.google.com` because those do not have an `http(s)?` or `www` in front of them.

EDIT #2:

I played around with this a little bit more and came up with an easier method of doing a find replace instead of breaking it up into an array, processing it and then turning it back into a string.

```
// YOUR WHITELIST ARRAY
$whitelist = array('google.com', 'yahoo.com', 'microsoft.com');

// TURN YOUR ARRAY INTO AN "OR" STRING TO BE USED FOR MATCHING
$whitelist_matching_string = implode('|', $whitelist);

// DO AN INLINE FIND/REPLACE
$string = preg_replace('~((http(s)?://)?(([-A-Z0-9.]+)?('.$whitelist_matching_string.')(\S+)?))~i', '<a href="http://$4">$1</a>', $string);

print $string;
```

Let me know if this works better for you.

Comment: The string is something like this:

    http://subdomain.google.com Lorem http://www.yahoo.com Ipsum is simply http://microsoft.com dummy text www.google.com of the printing and typesetting industry.

Comment: Okay, so you need to match the domains from a string with multiple domains?  Okay, NP.  I will revise my answer.

Comment: **Why the heck do you wrap a URL matching regexp in `/`?** For this `\/\/`? Just wrap it in `'~...~i'`. And no more escaping of `/` which is very common in URLs and HTMLs.

Comment: @CodeAngry could you add an example?

Comment: He's saying to change your REGEX string to something like this: `$pattern = '~\b((http(s?)://)|(?=www\.))(\S+)~is';` so you don't have to escape the slashes.

Comment: I made a second update to my post.  Give that a whirl and see if that works for you.